# java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm trying to start record video, but program crushes in line "recorder.start();". 
 This program was stable at **Huawei D1** (8 Mpx) , but on **HTC Desure C** (5 Mpx) program has started giving errors

Error:

```
W/dalvikvm(18833): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a8b228)
E/AndroidRuntime(18833): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18833): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

Code:

```
    public void startRec(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, String VideoName) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.unlock();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);
        setRecorderParams();
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());      
        recorder.setOutputFile(VideoName);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setRecorderParams() {   
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(30000);
        recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    }
```

Comment: are those recorderParams valid for your 2nd device aswell?

Comment: @ftp27 got solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in posting right parameters to recorder. Some devices don't provide some Video Encoders or Output Formats.

[VideoEncoder parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html)

Comment: How do you know which ones are supported or not

Comment: @ftp27 Please, give more details about what was the cause of the issue and how you solved it. This is not useful to anyone in the current form, as the vote count currently shows

Comment: The issue was years ago and I don't know much details. Maybe Google changed the page from the link and it doesn't help anymore.